Find an explicity formula for the inverse of the function $\textbf{f}$ given by $f_1=e^x\cos y$ and $f_2=e^x\sin y$

Let $\textbf{f}$ be given by $f_1=e^x\cos y$ and $f_2=e^x\sin y$, and put $\textbf{a}=(0,\pi/3)$, $\textbf{b}=\textbf f(a)$. Find
an explicity formula for the inverse of $\textbf{f}$, denoted
$\textbf{g}$, defined in a neighbourhood of $\textbf{b}$ such that $\textbf{g}(b)=a$.

Step 1: Finding $\textbf{a}=(0,\pi/3)$, $\textbf{b}=\textbf f(a)$
\begin{equation}
    f_1(0,\pi/3)=e^0\cos \pi/3, \ \ \ \ \ f_2(0,\pi/3)=e^0\sin \pi/3\implies\textbf{b}=\textbf f(a)=(\cos\pi/3,\sin\pi/3)
\end{equation}
Step 2. Go for the inverse of $\textbf{f}$:
Acording to Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis,  p.221, The Inverse function theorem:
\begin{equation}
    f_1(x,y)=e^x\cos y, \ \ \ \ \ f_2(x,y)=e^x\sin y
\end{equation}
writing in component form we arrive at
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &y_1=f_1(e^x,\cos y)\\
        &y_2=f_2(e^x,\sin y)
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Then, we associate to each $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ a function $\phi$, defined as:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &\phi_1=\textbf{x}+A^{-1}(\textbf{y}_1-\textbf{f}(x))\\
        &\phi_2=\textbf{x}+A^{-1}(\textbf{y}_2-\textbf{f}(x))
        \end{split}
\end{equation}
But there is not example on how to proceed in the book. Does anyone have an example or a solution on how to solve this?

Hint: $y_1^2+y_2^2=e^{2x}$ hence $x=\dots$

It beats me how he solved that.

Note that viewed as a map from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C$, $\mathbf f=\exp$. The inverse functions are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Branches_of_the_complex_logarithm

Are you aware of a complete solution to this type of problem on MSE?

Complete means that it has an answer that shows how to obtain the inverse function, and this type means multivariable.

If by "obtain" you mean "find an explicit formula", then no. Some multivariable (locally) bijective functions have an explicit (local) inverse, and other ones don't.

Then it would be best the question stands..

Excuse me (my english is weak), again, I don't understand. Do you mean one shouldn't close your (specific) question as a duplicate?

Yes, exactly. I have search on MSE, and can't find anything. Your suggestion is the best, but it doesn't show how to solve the difficult  part.

There is no difficult part in your  (specific) question, and it was solved in the dupe. As for the general question, if you want a more detailed answer than my comment, better edit it as new post.

"There is no difficult part"?. What is MSE meant for, if difficulty is defined by moderators who are Professors and ex Professors?

That is indeed subjective. But difficult or not, it is a duplicate.
